# I got an error while running an Android Project

Tags: android

I created an Android Application in Eclipse. After Running the project, I get this error:

`MyAndroid] Failed to install MyAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5554': device not found`

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Start the emulator prior running the project.

Comment: Do you have the emulator running? go to the DDMS perspective and look if there's any device

Answer (score 2):

Start your emulator and wait for it to setup completely. Make sure that when you run the "adb devices" command, you will see it in the list. If this does not help, create a new AVD following [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds.html) instructions and use the new AVD.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a device emulator running OR have a device connected to your development box via USB. You can run through this process by reviewing [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds.html) on how to manage Android Virtual Devices (AVDs).

Don't forget that before you're ready to publish to the Market, you should always test on an actual device!! AVDs are no subsitute for the real thing. Test on as many real devices as you can. A good article explains testing on actual [hardware here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html).